# Finding uppercase in linkedlist and returning new linkedlist with found elements?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, list, linked-list

I have to write a method which will search a linkedlist(ListNode, cointaining one char per listnode), finding all uppercase chars, copy them to a new ListNode and returning the new ListNode. This is my code so far, but it fails the JUnit testing (Provided by prof.)

This is list node:

```
public class ListNode {
    public char element;
    public ListNode next;

}
```

And this is the method ive wrote, which dont seem to work:

```
 public static ListNode copyUpperCase(ListNode head) {

    ListNode newListNode = mkEmpty();
    if(head == null){
        throw new ListsException("Lists: null passed to copyUpperCase");
    }else{
        char[] sss = toString(head).toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < sss.length ; i++ )
                if(Character.isUpperCase(sss[i])){
                    newListNode.element = sss[i];       
                }
                newListNode = newListNode.next;
        }           
    return newListNode;
}
```

What is worng with the code? Why does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @enterbios's answer (+1 for him), try the following:

```
public static ListNode toUpperCase(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null)
        throw new ListsException("Lists: null passed to copyUpperCase");

    ListNode newHead = null;
    ListNode current = null;

    char[] sss = toString(head).toCharArray();

    for (int i=0; i<sss.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(sss[i])) {
            if (current == null) {
                current = mkEmpty();
                newHead = current;
            } else {
                current.next = mkEmpty();
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.element = sss[i];
        }
    }
    return newHead;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create newListNode.next somewhere. I don't see it in provided code snippet.
Try changing your method like:

```
 public static ListNode copyUpperCase(ListNode head) {

    ListNode newListNode = mkEmpty(); 
    ListNode newHead = newListNode;   //KEEP HEAD OF NEW LINKED LIST
    if(head == null){
        throw new ListsException("Lists: null passed to copyUpperCase");
    }else{
        char[] sss = toString(head).toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < sss.length ; i++ )
            if(Character.isUpperCase(sss[i])){
                newListNode.element = sss[i];
                newListNode.next = mkEmpty();   //CREATE NEW INSTANCES INSIDE LOOP
                newListNode = newListNode.next; //MOVING FORWARD TO NEXT NODE, newListNode is the last node of new linked list
            }
    }
    return newHead;
}
```

Comment: Just as a precaution, this will result in an empty node at the end of your list. (I don't know if that is a problem or not, just wanted to point it out)

Comment: "XabIdRXA7pX", this is the string, which will turned into char element in the ListNode. After running copyUpperCase-method, it only return "RA". Shouldnt it return "XIRXAX" ? Why is that?

Comment: I see, I think it would be a problem @dcharms

Comment: +1 because I expanded upon your answer and I hate when people snipe points from someone that was close.